# Rails recurring_select gem week start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recurring-events

I'm using recurring_select gem in my Rails project but can't find a way to specify week_start param, so that Monday would appear first while choosing the weekly schedule. Is there a way to do this?

Here's the source code of gem https://github.com/GetJobber/recurring_select

Here's what the schedule picker currently looks like:

[image]

And here's the resulting code of `recurring` column:

`{:validations=>{:day=>[1, 5]}, :rule_type=>"IceCube::WeeklyRule", :interval=>1, :week_start=>0}`

I wouldn't like to override this in my controller, I'm sure there's a way to specify this as a param in a view or sth like that, but my frontend skills are too low to understand this.
I've tried passing `week_start: 1` as a form helper param, but this did not help

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not entirely clear, and the location of the option is not entirely logical, but according to the [source](https://github.com/GetJobber/recurring_select/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/recurring_select_dialog.js.coffee.erb#L168), I am guessing you have to define the `first_day_of_week` which for some reason is located inside the `texts` configuration block. So something like

```
$.fn.recurring_select.texts = {
  first_day_of_week: 1
}
```

Not sure how the number is interpreted, 1 is monday and 0 is sunday?